# Does multi-classing provides weapon proficiency of the guest class?

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing, proficiency

As a Wizard, multi-classing into Fighter (through Multi-class Feat), would the Fighter multi-class provide the weapon proficiencies that the Fighter otherwise gains from its class?

I found no evidence of this sort, but I would be happy to gain clarification. I check PHB 1-3, but maybe there is an update somewhere in Dungeon/Dragon magazines and so forth...

Thank you!

Comment: Are you multiclassing using a Multiclass Feat? Those are pretty clear about what they offer you in advantages. Or are you using a different method, like a Hybrid?

Comment: @Erik I updated my question, yes, it is about the Multiclass Feat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the multiclass feats say what you get from them.  Many, but not all implement using classes' multiclass feats grant proficiency with that class' implements, but even then the feat has to say which implements it's granting- some don't grant all of the parent class' implements.  Weapon using classes don't generally grant proficiency with that class' weapons on their multiclass feats.

Note that the feat Weapon Proficiency can grant any character proficiency with any weapon.  This is in contrast to implements- there is no generic implement proficiency feat, and some (e.g. Holy Symbols) are available only through your class or multiclass feats.